# In python chevron, how do I create a list of objects using templates without chevron automatically url quoting the content?

Tags: python, linux, mustache

I have 2 chevron templates:

```
datatemplate:
<div>
<li>"this is data": {{ data }}<\li>
</div>
```

```
listdata:
<ul>
{{ datalists }}
</ul>
```

I do this to generate a list:

```
datalists=""
for i in array_of_data:
 tmp=chevron.render(datatemplate,i)
 datalists+=tmp

final_result=chevron.render(listdataa,{datalists:datalists})
```

The problem being that double quotes get url quoted on the final chevron render. How do I get chevron to render the fragment without automatically url quoting the final result?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <li>{{ data|safe }}</li>
</div>
```

Doing this doesn't work. Everything gets stripped, and nothing appears. I've reedited the data template a little. It's the quotation marks in the template that gets url quoted that is the issue.

I solved this by removing the html quoting in the chevron renderer.py file and removing the pycache.